Gifsicle '--explode' via web not working as expected
I am importing gifsicle via 'https://unpkg.com/gifsicle-wasm-browser@1.5.16/dist/gifsicle.min.js' and have successfully used it to optimize my gif files generated with gif.js.
However, I am now attempting to use --explode to extract the individual frames from the provided 'savedGif', but am getting stuck. (would love to be able to do exactly what https://ezgif.com/split is doing....) All documentation for gifsicle points to each exploded image being stored at 'saved.gif.001' 'saved.gif.002' etc.... but I am not sure how this works outside of a command line (since I am doing this via the web)...
Here is the code I have so far:
`if (savedGif != null) {
            try {
                // Explode savedGif
                await gifsicle.run({
                    input: [{ file: savedGif, name: 'saved.gif' }],
                    command: ['--explode saved.gif -o /out/saved.gif']
                });

                // Fetch the list of frames
                const frameCount = await getFrameCount('/out/', 'saved.gif.');
                
                // Read frames into gifStack and wait for them to load
                for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
                    const frameName = `saved.gif.${String(i).padStart(3, '0')}`;
                    const frame = await fetch(`/path/to/exploded/frames/${frameName}`).then(res => res.blob());
                    const imageData = new Image();
                    imageData.src = URL.createObjectURL(frame);

                    await new Promise((resolveLoad) => {
                        imageData.onload = () => {
                            gifStack.push(imageData);
                            resolveLoad();
                        };
                    });
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('GIF explosion error:', error);
                loadingMessage.textContent = 'Error exploding GIF.';
                setTimeout(() => {
                    loadingModal.style.display = 'none';
                }, 3000);

                reject(error);
                return;
            }
        }`

I am getting no errors when running this, and when I try to send the output to the console I also get nothing. I've also thought that maybe I could trying something like
` const output = await gifsicle.run({
                    input: [{ file: savedGif, name: 'saved.gif' }],
                    command: ['--explode saved.gif -o /out/saved.gif']
                });` 

and then loop through output[0] for each frame, but this also did not work...
Any thoughts or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

I'm dumb and I literally just answered my own question. I was trying to solve this via the gifsicle man page documentation. but I should have been looking here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifsicle-wasm-browser
